# ActiveRecord - prevent DB connection when calling Model.new

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Every time I call Model.new, and before calling .save, ActiveRecord seems to get a database connection (which might make sense since it needs to get the field names).

How do I prevent this from happening? I don't intend to save the model into the database. I'm just creating it and then passing it to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a version of the model that doesn't inherit ActiveRecord::Base Then you can pass it around as a data object and leave your database alone until you actually need it.

Comment: I want to use it both ways. As both an active record when I do intend to save it, and not when I intend to pass it around w/o saving.